# Loop through all worksheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to repeat this code on all the worksheets in a workbook.

There may sometimes be 1-2 worksheets sometimes 50+.

```
Sub HoursTotal()
'
' HoursTotal Macro
'

Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
Range("G1").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help with your code as well, try to avoid using `.Select`. It will make your code run a bit slower. You can find more information about it from [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Sub HoursTotal()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
        ws.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
        ws.Range("G1").Select 'I don't think you need this line but I included it anyways
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple modification of your current code should do it:

```
Sub HoursTotal()
'
' HoursTotal Macro
'

Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws in Worksheets

    ws.Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
    ws.Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
    ws.Range("G1").Select

Next ws

End Sub
```

But here's what it looks like without the `Select`'s

```
Sub HoursTotal()
'
' HoursTotal Macro
'

Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws in Worksheets

    ws.Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
    ws.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
    ws.Range("G1").Select

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Haha I figured because it was included in the original code without any action taken upon it, the user wanted the ending active cell to be G1

Comment: That's what I thought but ...ooo..yuck! they're soo gross!! +1 for thinking about the OP's point of view,

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the worksheet so that excel can make changes to it.

`Sub HoursTotal()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
    ws.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
    ws.Range("G1").Select 'I don't think you need this line but I included it anyways
Next
```

End Sub`

Comment: No, you don't need to `.Activate` or `.Select`